# Cannot start ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

I just finish installing Ubuntu on my windows 7 computer. When I restart my computer, it does not give me the option to boot up Ubuntu, it automatically start windows7. What should I do to start ubuntu

Comment: try boot-repair.

Comment: What's the Ubuntu version?? and just to make it more clear.. have you installed Ubuntu alongside Windows or on a separate partition?